# show that $\lim _{x\rightarrow 0}\sin\frac{1}{x}$ doesn't exist by using the Squeeze Theorem

Tags: calculus

Exercise 4, page 92 from Guidorizzi' book *Calculo* (in Portuguese) he asks to show that $\lim _{x\rightarrow 0}\sin\frac{1}{x}$ doesn't exist. I know how to do that by using two differents sequences, but that exercise is in the Squeeze Theorem section. So, is it possible to show that $\lim _{x\rightarrow 0}\sin\frac{1}{x}$ doesn't exist by using the Squeeze Theorem?

Comment: What do you use the squeeze theorem for again?

Comment: To prove this without using the squeeze theorem: Produce two sequences $a_n$ and $b_n$ that converge to zero but that sine of 1 upon each of these goes to different limits. I'll tell you that one of them is the sequence $a_n = 1/2n\pi$ the other is....

Comment: The squeeze theorem says that a limit *does* exist, and is not an "if and only if", so you cannot literally prove that a limit does not exist using the squeeze theorem.

Comment: @Carl Mummert: I found it very strange, because the author haven't defined sequences yet.

Comment: My guess is to look back through the section to see if the author proved any other limit does not converge; that might show what he had in mind for that exercise. Sometimes the placement of exercises is very mysterious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The usual squeeze theorem only says that a limit does exist, and it is not phrased as an "if and only if", so it can't literally be used to test for nonconvergence.

However, we can do something "squeeze theorem like". Given a limit $\lim_{x \to c} f(x)$, we can come up with "universal" functions $g(x)$ and $h(x)$, which take values in $[-\infty, \infty]$, such that for all $x$, $g(x) \leq f(x) \leq h(x)$, and such that the limit exists if and only if $\lim_{x \to c} g(x)$ and $\lim_{x \to c}h(x)$ both exist and are equal.

To make the notation easier, suppose $c = 0$. Both $g$ and $h$ will be even functions, so we only need to define them for non-negative $x$. We let $g(0) = -\infty$ and for $x > 0$ we let $$g(x) = \inf \{ f(y) : y \in [-x,0)\cup(0,x]\}$$

Similarly, we let $h(0) = \infty$ and for $x > 0$ we let
$$h(x) = \sup \{ f(y) : y \in [-x,0)\cup(0,x]\}$$

Now, as we move towards $0$, $h(x)$ will decrease and $g(x)$ will increase, and so they will both have limits at $0$. If these limits are equal, then $g$ and $h$ can be used in the squeeze theorem to show that the limit of $f(x)$ exists. On the other hand, if the limits are not equal, then an argument directly using the definition of limits can be used to show the limit of $f(x)$ does not exist.

For $f(x) = \sin(1/x)$, we have that $g(x) = -1$ for all $x > 0$ and $h(x) = 1$ for all $x > 0$, so this method can be used to show that the $\lim_{x \to 0} \sin(1/x)$ does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the sequences $$x_n=\frac 1 {2n\pi}$$ and $$y_n=\frac 1 {\frac{\pi n}2+2\pi}$$

Clearly, both sequences go to $0$. However, setting $f(x)=\sin(x^{-1})$,

$$f(x_n)=0$$

for each $n$, and

$$f(y_n)=1$$ for each $n$. The sequential characterization of continuity says $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}f(x)$ can't exist.